# How does dynamic programming work in this example(generating the tables )

Tags: dynamic-programming

> For example, a sequence has the defined growth property: if it is a
>   sequence of positive integers $a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}....a_{n}$ and such
>   that:
>
> 1. $a_{1}=1.$
> 2. $a_{n+1} \leq$ Max$_{1\leq i \leq n}$ ($a_{i}+1$)
>
> We can quickly compute the number of such sequences of length n with the power of dynamic programing:
>
> Let sequence(l, m)  be the number of possible sequences with length
>   l and maximum number in the sequence m. The total number of such
>   sequences for a length can be calculated by summing all the sequences
>   with maximum value ranging from 1 to n for length l. The recurrence
>   can be described as:
>
> sequence(l,m) = sequence(l-1, m-1 ) + m * sequence(l-1,m);
>
> (sequence (l,1)=1, sequence(l,m)=0 if l< m)
>
> As we create a table of size l * m, where we fill the matrix column
>   by column. The base case: the first column of the table sequence(l, 1)
>   = 1 and for the subproblems where l < m the number of sequences will be 0 since the maximum element in sequence can't be bigger than the
>   length of sequence. We can now fill the table in the second column and
>   apply the recurrence relation for every cell and obtain the value fro
>   all combinations of l and m. Finally, We can sum up the last row to
>   calculate the number of sequences.

Understand that the text already gives hint for creating the table. 
but I am still struggling to visualize it. First of all,  What exactly is this sequence?

$a_{2} = a_{1+1} \leq max_{1 \leq i \leq 1}(a_{i}+1) $ which mean i can only be 1. Then $a_{2} \leq  max(2)$

and $a_{3}\leq max(3)$ but what are some example of such sequence ?
Any more guidance for completing the table?

What is exactly m in sequence(l, m)?  Where should we place $a_{4}$ in the table of l * m?

Comment: A minor typo, "sequence(l,max)=0 if l< m" should be "sequence(l,m)=0 if l< m".

Comment: thank you, updated the text to avoid any future unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Please credit the source of all quoted material in the question.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Answer (score 1):

Here are all such sequences of length 1.

```
[1]
```

Here are all such sequences of length 2.

```
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
```

Here are all such sequences of length 3.

```
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]


[1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Here are all such sequences of length 4.

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 2]


[1, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 3]

[1, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 3]

[1, 2, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 3]


[1, 2, 3, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Please observe how the sequences grow longer and longer with the condition 
$$a_{n+1} \leq \max_{1\le i \le n} (a_{i}+1) = 1+\max_{1\le i \le n} a_{i}$$
as well as the recurrence relation
$$ \text{sequence}(l,m) = \text{sequence}(l-1, m-1 ) + m * \text{sequence}(l-1,m).$$

---

> $a_{2} = a_{1+1} \leq \max_{1 \leq i \leq 1}(a_{i}+1) $ which mean i can only be 1. Then $a_{2} \leq  \max(2)$. and $a_{3}\leq \max(3)$.

Yes, $a_{2} \leq  \max(2)=2$. However, $a_{3}\leq \max(a_1+1, a_2+1)$. If $a_2=1$, then $a_3\le \max(1+1, 1+1)=2$. While $a_3\le \max(3)=3$ is true, it might be relaxed too much.

---

Let us see how we are going to fill the two dimensional array sequence($m$,$l$).

For example, how to use the following relation?
$$\text{sequence}(4,4) = \text{sequence}(3, 3 ) + 4 * \text{sequence}(3,4)\,.$$
We know sequence$(3,3) = 1$ since there is only one sequence of length 3 and maximum number 3, $[1,2,3]$ or sequence$(3,3) = 1 + 3 * 0 = 1$. There is no sequence of length of length 3 and maximum number 4, since the maximum number in any sequence of length 3 is at most 3. So $$\text{sequence}(4,4) = 1 + 4 * 0 = 1\,,$$
which corresponds to the unique sequence of length 4 and maximum number 4, $[1,2,3,4]$.

---

> What is exactly $m$ in $\text{sequence}(l, m)$? Where should we place $a_4$ in the table of $l * m$?

It looks like you need to understand the recurrence relation.

$$ \text{sequence}(l,m) = \text{sequence}(l-1, m-1 ) + m * \text{sequence}(l-1,m),$$

where $\text{sequence}(l,m)$, $l\ge2$, $m\ge1$ is the number of sequences whose length is $l$ and whose maximum number is $m$. For example, a sequence $(a_1, a_2,a_3,a_4)$ is a sequence of length 4 and whose maximum number is $\max(a_1, a_2,a_3,a_4)$. If that maximum number is $k$, it contributes 1 to $\text{sequence}(4, k)$ if it satisfies the two conditions. For example, sequence $(1,2,3,2)$ contributes 1 to $\text{sequence}(4, 3)$ while sequence $(1,1,2,2)$ contributes 1 to $\text{sequence}(4, 2)$.

Let $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_l$ be such a sequence. Let us consider its first $l-1$ items, $a_1, a_2,\cdots, a_{l-1}$.

- The maximum number of $a_1, a_2,\cdots, a_{l-1}$ is smaller than $m-1$. Then $$a_{l} = a_{(l-1)+1}\leq \max_{1\le i \le l-1} (a_{i}+1) = 1+\max_{1\le i \le l-1} a_{i}\lt m$$, which contradicts that fact that the maximum number of all of them is $m.

  So this situation cannot happen.
- The maximum number of $a_1, a_2,\cdots, a_{l-1}$ is $m-1$. Then $a_l$ must be $m$. Otherwise, the maximum number of the whole sequence will be $m-1$ instead of the required $m$.

  So for each sequence counted in $\text{sequence}(l-1, m-1 )$, we have a sequence that should be counted in $\text{sequence}(l, m)$. We have a summand $\text{sequence}(l-1, m-1)$
- The maximum number of $a_1, a_2,\cdots, a_{l-1}$ is $m$. Then $a_l$ can be anyone of $1, 2, \cdots, m$ $m$. So for each sequence counted in $\text{sequence}(l-1, m)$, we have $m$ sequences that should be counted in $\text{sequence}(l, m)$. That is, we have a summand $ m * \text{sequence}(l-1, m)$.

Combining all three cases above, we obtain that recurrence relation.

Comment: Yes. It was done relaxing too much that I mentally just skip the something important. Where should we put $a_{4}$ in the table of l * m ?  bit confused by "Let sequence(l, m) be the number of possible sequences with length l and maximum number in the sequence m."

Comment: Whenever you see `sequence(l, m)`, read it as `myCount(l,m)` like a mathematical function or `myCount[m][l]` like a Java 2D array,  since it maps a pair of integers to another integer.

Comment: Why [1, 1, 3] is not in the sequence of length3 again?  It seems totally valid one,  it never exceed the length and the maximum is 3.

Comment: For sequence [1,1,3], a_1=1, a_1=1, a_3=3. Now let us the requirement, $a_{n+1} \leq\max_{1\leq i \leq n}(a_{i}+1)$. Let $n=2$. We get $a_3\le\max_{1\le i\le2}(a_i+1)=\max(a_1+1, a_2+1)=\max(2,2)=2$. However, 3>2. (That is why I said "it might be relaxed too much" in my answer.)

Comment: How would you utilize sequence(,)=sequence(−1,−1)+∗sequence(−1,).
As sequence(4,4), the sequence of the length of 4 and has 4 as maximum number.
equal to sequence(3,3) +3∗sequence(3,4), which can't really add up together. sequence(3,3) = 5 + 3* 0 =5  while from sequence (4,4) is 15 in your example.

Comment: Please check the update. Note that [1, 1, 1, 1] is sequence of length 4 and maximum number 1. $\ $[1, 1, 1, 2] is sequence of length 4 and maximum number 2.